# Android-Command to run dmtracedump

Tags: android

how to run dmtracedump in android.what is the exact command to run it in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Run it with no arguments, and it'll print a "usage" line.

Depending on what release you're using, some of the options may crash or hang indefinitely.  You should be safe with "dmtracedump -o ", which just formats the raw data into human-readable format.

It's really only useful for debugging the tracing mechanism.  "traceview" is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Type this command:

dmtracedump -t 40 -g dmtrace.png /path/dmtrace.trace

Let me know, if any issue occurs.

Note: You need to install Graphviz, first from http://www.graphviz.org/.

Thanks